# Use event.key instead of event.keyCode

Tags: javascript

So lets say that I have code that checks if an keypress was a number

```
if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) {
// number entered, do something
} else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
// backspace pressed
}
```

How would I go about changing these checks to use event.key as event.keyCode is depreciated. Is it as easy as I think it is?

In particular how to I use e.key with the backspace key

Comment: Do you really want to check the keyCode or the character that was generated? The [*keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) just tells you the key that was pressed, it doesn't tell you the character it generated, e.g. if one or more modifier keys are also pressed, pressing the "G" key might return "g", "G", "©", "˝", and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change it to use the name of the key being pressed. For letters it is the letter pressed, a = "a", A = "A", z = "z" etc. Number is the the string version of the number 1 = "1", 2 = "2" etc. For control keys it is the name of the key, ctrl = "Control", backspace = "Backspace", etc.

A list can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values)

So if you are needing to test for number range you can get the `key` value and coerce it to a number and just do the applicable comparison, as for backspace just compare against the string `"Backspace"`

```
//coerce it to a number
numKey = +e.key;
if (!isNaN(numKey) && numKey >= 0 && numKey <= 9 ) {
// number entered, do something
} else if (e.key == "Backspace") {
// backspace pressed
}
```